# Rails rspec test fails when switching from sqlite3 to mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec-rails

I have a small rails application, where I had originally been using sqlite3, then decided to switch to mysql. After I switched, one of my rspec tests broke, but I can't tell why (it was working fine when using sqlite3, and checking the functionality via the actual page appears to work correctly).

My tests are as follows:

```
before(:each) do
    @a = FactoryGirl.create(:a)
    @b = FactoryGirl.create(:b)
    @relationship = @a.connector.build( :b_id => @b)
    @relationship.save
end
```

Test 1:

```
it "should have the right b" do
    @relationship.b.should == @b
end
```

Test 2:

```
it "should have the right a" do
    @relationship.a.should == @a
end
```

In my tests, test 1 fails, while test 2 passes successfully when using mysql (both path when using sqlite3).
As far as I know, I shouldn't require any changes to the tests themselves if I am just switching databases, so can anyone tell if I am doing something wrong? Or if I need to add something to refresh the databases?

On a related note, what is the recommended way to debug issues in the rspec tests themselves, especially if the actual development works, but the tests fail?
(I am using Rails 3.1 and rspec-rails 2.10.1).

Thanks in advance for any input,

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue; the problem was being caused by buggy caching behaviour in my model.

In the first spec, I was caching the first object, which was created with ID 1.  When recreated for the second spec, the object was created with ID 1 on SQLite3, and with ID 2 on MySQL.

So, the caching behaviour was working by luck when tested on SQLite3, and failing consistently on MySQL.